# One element of String array won't print into UITextField in Swift4. Casting to Any or String

Tags: ios, swift4, ssid

The offending element is the

```
let mSSIDDATA = SSIDDict["SSIDDATA"]
```

field. If I leave it as it is, it prints out to the log window as shown here.

> Looking up SSID info for en0 SSIDDict Values: ["SSID": SKYF7BFF,
>   "BSSID": 7c:4c:a5:c:8b:15, "SSIDDATA": <534b5946 37424646>]
>
> mSSID: SKYF7BFF
>
> mBSSID: 7c:4c:a5:c:8b:15
>
> mSSIDDATA: <534b5946 37424646>
>
> SSID: SKYF7BFF
>
> BSSID: 7c:4c:a5:c:8b:15
>
> SSIDDATA: <534b5946 37424646>
>
> =========

However - It doesn't print out into the `UITextField` in the iOS interface. The other two do, but this third one doesn't, and I can't figure out why.?
If I change the `[String : Any]` to `[String : AnyObject]` it creates another whole set of warnings and errors.

So basically, how do I convert that `mSSIDDATA` to a string that the `UITextField` can handle?

```
            guard let SSIDDict: [String : Any]  = (unwrappedCFDictionaryForInterface as NSDictionary) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("System error: interface information is not a string-keyed dictionary")
            return false
        }
        print("SSIDDict Values: \(SSIDDict)")
        let mSSID = SSIDDict["SSID"] as? String
        let mBSSID = SSIDDict["BSSID"] as? String
        let mSSIDDATA = SSIDDict["SSIDDATA"] //as? String

        print("mSSID: \(mSSID ?? "")")
        vSSID.text = mSSID
        print("mBSSID: \(mBSSID ?? "")")
        vBSSID.text = mBSSID
        print("mSSIDDATA: \(mSSIDDATA ?? "")")
        vSSIDDATA.text = mSSIDDATA as? String

        for d in SSIDDict.keys {
            print("\(d): \(SSIDDict[d]!)")
        }



    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name `mSSIDDATA` implies and the output `<...>` indicates the type of the value is `Data`

```
if let mSSIDDATA = SSIDDict["SSIDDATA"] as? Data {
    print(String(data: mSSIDDATA, encoding : .utf8)!) // SKYF7BFF
}
```

Practically it's the `Data` representation of the `mSSID` string value.

Comment: Thanks, so this works and puts the converted string into the UITextField. like this. vSSIDDATA.text = (String(data: mSSIDDATA as! Data, encoding : .utf8)!) Where vSSIDATA is the UITextField. Is it possible then to not convert the data, but still print it to the UITextField?

Comment: If you want to print `<534b5946 37424646>` then write `print(String(describing: mSSIDDATA as NSData))`

Comment: Excellent. Looks like I'm doing some in-depth study on Data. This works.
            print(String(describing: mSSIDDATA as! NSData))
            vSSIDDATA.text = (String(describing: mSSIDDATA as! NSData))

Answer (score 2):

Your „SSIDDATA” is most likely od `Data` type - you need to convert it to `String`. You can USD the [init(data:encoding:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1418413-init) on String to achieve this.